# Making a page centered as long as it does not overflow in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a web-page, which has a body that expands over time (by user clicks and such), that I want to be centered (vertically).

I also want it to be scroll-able when the content exceeds the page's height (when it overflows), but then it has to be aligned to the top of the page.

I want it to behave like this, and I want to achieve it with `flexbox`:

[image: Target Behavior]

Any ideas?

Comment: `html {display:flex;min-height:100%;} body{width:100%;margin:auto;}` should be a start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically center a content area until it reaches a certain height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973442/vertically-center-a-content-area-until-it-reaches-a-certain-height)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus that works, but is there a way to do it without margin: auto?

Comment: @Blackhole no, not really.

Comment: @NadavTasher yes, there is bunch of ways without using *margin: auto*. check my answer

Comment: Why doesn't it? Looks exactly like your problem to me (the 100px of the upper side being 0px in your case).

Comment: @Blackhole because I want to achieve it with flexbox

Answer (score 0):

If possible define new tags with class attributes "container" and "box"

window -> .container

body -> .box

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    this is box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this answer does not solve my issue with flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

here is one for the `flex box`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background: darkcyan;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background: cyan;
  width: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one does not work for me. You cant scroll to the top.

Comment: mean you want the `content` inside the `cantainer` to be scrollable when you shrink

Comment: @NadavTasher now check I made an edit, when you shrink the page the `content` turn to scrollable one

Comment: run  a snippet in full page and try to shrink the page content instead of overflowing it will turn into srollable one